# Alignment issues with longtable and siunitx

Tags: longtable, siunitx

First a minimal working sample is given:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{ctexbook}
\usepackage[top=3.2cm,bottom=2.4cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%实现表格中数字按小数点对齐%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}
%mode:math(正文数字old),text(正文数字非old),主要针对表格
%%%解决表格标题与下方表格过近%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}
%%%跨页表格%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{longtable}
%%%表格标题与前后文字间距%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2pt} 
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%%%表格与页面左右边缘之间的矩离均为０%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt} \setlength{\LTright}{0pt} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l|c S|S S|S|S|S}%@{\extracolsep{\fill}}设置使得后面所有列间距可以伸展到预定义的表格宽度。
    \hline\hline
    \caption{标准字体命令与字号的对应值} %\label{}加在\caption{}的括号中
    \\\hline\hline
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\texttt{zihao=5}}\vline&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\texttt{zihao=-4}}\vline &\texttt{10pt}&\texttt{11pt}&\texttt{12pt}\\\cline{2-8}  
    字体命令&字号&bp值&字号&bp值&pt值&pt值&pt值\\\hline
    \endfirsthead%第一页表头
    \hline
    字体命令&字号&bp值&字号&bp值&pt值&pt值&pt值\\\hline
    \endhead%续页表头
    \verb|\tiny|&七号&5.5&小六&6.5&5&6&6  \\\hline
    \verb|\scriptsize|&小六&6.5&六号&7.5&7&8&8  \\\hline
    \verb|\footnotesize|&六号&7.5&小五&9&8&9&10  \\\hline
    \verb|\small|&小五&9&五号&10.5&9&10&11  \\\hline
    \verb|\normalsize|&五号&10.5&小四&12&10&11&12  \\\hline
    \verb|\large|&小四&12&小三&15&12&12&14  \\\hline
    \verb|\Large|&小三&15&小二&18&14&14&17  \\\hline
    \verb|\LARGE|&小二&18&二号&22&17&17&20  \\\hline
    \verb|\huge|&二号&22&小一&24&20&20&25  \\\hline
    \verb|\Huge|&一号&26&一号&26&25&25&25  \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with **XeLatex**, I got a pdf as follows

[image]

My **QUESTIONS** are:

1. How to make the cline (the line below `zihao=5`) from the first vertical line?
2. How to make the texts of column 6-8 centering?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1: `\cline{2-8}` instead of `\hline`.

2: change the format of numbers. For columns 6-8, it should be `S[table-format=2.0]`. For columns 3 and  5, `S[table-format=2.1]`. I don't see why you use an `S` column type for columns 2 and 4 since they have no numbers to align.
Add in the preamble `\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}`Last : in an `S` column, non number contents (e.g. column heads) are centred by adding a pair of braces around the contents (except in case of `\multicolumn`).

Comment: For your 1, it seems that your don't read my codes clearly; and for your 2, it doesn't work!

Comment: Your code is not fully clear to me, I confess, as I don't read Chinese. However for point 2, I gave you the standard answer for european languages. For point 1, I had not seen your code indeed. Maybe this is due to `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`  in the preamble of the table. It can result in strange things sometimes. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: It may become well, but I want to make the table have a length of textwidth in long table environment.

Comment: Why  don't use use `tabularx` , loading the `ltablex` package (it brings the functionalities of `long table` to `tabularx`)?

Comment: Because I need the table to be broken by page.

Comment: With `ltablex`, tabularx *can* be broken by page.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `\keepXColumns` directive in your preamble.